# Turning Img file into string JS/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to turn an image into a string in javascript and Node? I want to do this to make an image comparing software and I know how to compare strings. Thanks.

Comment: Its possible to get the rgba values of each pixel.

Comment: what do you mean by comparing? do you need to know where there are differences or simply if the pictures are the same?

Comment: I simply want to know if the pictures are the same.

Comment: I've been using the base64-img npm module but no matter what images I put in, it returns the same string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I used fs.readFile() to accomplish this. I used the result from the readFile() to get the string. Thanks.